# Meteor template not receiving it's manager values

Tags: meteor

This is a very confusing bug, that seems like it's simply something fundamentally wrong.

Here's my template, which is showing up correctly.

```html
<template name="user">
    {{#each emails}}
        {{address}}
    {{/each}}

    {{#if customer}}
        {{> userCustomer customer}}
    {{else}}
        Sign up to be a customer.
        <form id="customerSignup">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input name="firstname" value="" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
            <button type="submit">Become a customer!</button>
        </form>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Here's my js. When I submit the form, this event handler isn't called. The page tries to post the form arguments in the url, and the console log doesn't happen, in fact *nothing* is logged at all, no errors or anything. Other things very similar to this are working fine.

```js
Template.user.events({
    'submit form#customerSignup': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('what???');
            // Other logic
    }
});
```

The only difference I can find between this and other fully functional things is this line in my router:

```js
this.route('user', {data: function() { return Meteor.user(); }});
```

Here's an example of something that works just fine.

```html
<template name="login">
    Sign in:
    {{signinError}}
    <form id="signin">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" value="" type="text" placeholder="Email"/>

        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password" />

        <button type="submit">Sign in!</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

```js
Template.login.events({
    'submit form#signin': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        Meteor.loginWithPassword( /* etc logic */ );
    },
});
```

Help!!! Very confused. This is basic Meteor stuff that seems to be broken for no reason. Is it the differently set context screwing things up?

Comment: are you sure that `<button type="submit">Become a customer!</button>` does what you think it does? have you tried `<input type="submit" value="Become a customer!"></input>` instead?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, you could use `click` event instead of `submit`.

Comment: Yeah @ChristianFritz, I just tried that change, and it made no difference. Also, I've done this exact same thing in different places with `button` and it's worked just fine.

Comment: @Cuberto, there are no errors or outputs of any kind in the console.

Comment: Also, I'm having this kind of problem with almost all of my templates/managers lately. It's almost as if I made a change to my project specification or *something*, and now any templates I make aren't talking to their managers correctly. Could it have to do with my directory structure? I've been very careful to follow the directions about client vs server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like a silent error somewhere *else* in my javascript file was causing this portion to silently fail. I don't know why, and I especially don't know why it wasn't saying anything about it, but now it's working fine. Ah the mysteries!!